# Finding the number of pairs of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a set $S$ has $n$ elements, with $T \subseteq S$, find the number of pairs of sets $(A,B)$ such that $A \subseteq S$, $B \subseteq S$, and $A-B=T$.

I drew a diagram
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47tjP.png) to help visualize things. My professor said it you have to think about the choices of where you can pick elements from, so the answer is $3^n$, but I still can't see how he got this. Any elucidation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor is wrong (if you quoted them correctly).

For each element, you independently have one of two independent binary choices, whether to include it in $A$ and/or in $B$, for a total of $4$ choices for each element.

Only one of these $4$ choices leads to an element $x$ being in $A-B$, namely $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$. The other three lead to $x\not\in A-B$. Thus we have $1$ choice for each element $x\in T$ and $3$ choices for each element $x\not\in T$, and these are all independent, so overall there are $3^{|S-T|}=3^{|S|-|T|}$ possibilities.

Comment: My apologies, I did not correctly quote my professor. Thanks for the clear and concise explanation.